# Magento2 programmatically adding a custom option

Tags: magento2, custom-options, programmatically

I'm trying to programmatically add a custom option to a product, there are no errors being returned, but the custom option doesn't get added. I've tried a few methods to achieve this, without much luck.

Here's my code as it stands:

```
$product = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productID);

$productOption = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option');
$productOption->setProduct($product);
$productOption->setTitle('Text');
$productOption->setType('area');
$productOption->setIsRequire(1);
$productOption->setValues([
    'title' => 'Text',
    'price' => '1.00',
    'max_characters' => '50',
    'price_type' => 'fixed',
    'sort_order' => '1'
]);
$product->addOption($productOption);
$product->save();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've now tried a different method:

```
$product = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productID);
$product->unsetOptions();
$product->setHasOptions(1);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$product->getOptionInstance()->addOption([
    'title' => 'Text',
    'type' => 'area',
    'is_require' => 1,
    'values' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Text',
            'price' => '1.00',
            'price_type' => 'fixed',
            'max_characters' => '50'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
[Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception] Invalid option value
```

However, I cannot figure out what's invalid.

Comment: Have you get any solution. I faced same issue while adding product custom option value ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292966/magento-2-add-product-option-custom-value-in-product-rest-api

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to specify values for the option type you are trying to add. Please try example below.

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface $customOption */
$customOption = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface');
$customOption->setTitle('Text')
    ->setType('area')
    ->setIsRequire(true)
    ->setSortOrder(1)
    ->setPrice(1.00)
    ->setPriceType('fixed')
    ->setMaxCharacters(50)
    ->setProductSku($product->getSku());
$customOptions[] = $customOption;
$product->setOptions($customOptions)->save();
```

Also, you can find a lot of examples on how to add products, attributes, options, etc in fixtures for integration tests. For instance, take a look in dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Catalog/_files

Comment: Got it working using your example. Do you know any examples for adding linked products for Bundle products?

Comment: Nice advice with tests! They can be much more up-to-date with current version of Magento (as there are a lot of updates these days).

Comment: Hi Igor, I tried above but it is giving unable to handle request page. can you tell what should have gone wrong??

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292966/magento-2-add-product-option-custom-value-in-product-rest-api

Comment: not work give this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getOptionId() on string

Comment: The method "save" shouldn't be called directly from Model, according to Magento latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another sample code that can import product custom options from array. The basic and required field are added in the code. You can add more field as you need. you can import all of type of custom options with this code. I have checked the code can update options attribute and prices also.

**This is a sample array data**

```
$datas = array(
        array(
            "sku" => "951391-1-1",
            "attributes" => '[{"title":"Add \"I\'m a pro\" on the back title", "type":"checkbox", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"1", "values":[{"title":"Add \"I\'m a pro\" on the back", "price":"2.000000", "price_type":"fixed", "sku":null, "sort_order":"1"}, {"title":"Add my name", "price":"6.000000", "price_type":"fixed", "sku":null, "sort_order":"2"}]}, {"title":"Add my name title", "type":"field", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"2", "price":"0.000000", "price_type":"fixed"}, {"title":"Test area title", "type":"area", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"3", "price":"16.000000", "price_type":"fixed"}, {"title":"Test file title", "type":"file", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"5", "price":"4.000000", "price_type":"fixed"}, {"title":"Test dropdown title", "type":"drop_down", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"6", "values":[{"title":"test dropdown 1", "price":"7.000000", "price_type":"fixed", "sku":null, "sort_order":"1"}, {"title":"test dropdown 2", "price":"8.000000", "price_type":"fixed", "sku":null, "sort_order":"2"}]}, {"title":"Test radio title", "type":"radio", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"7", "values":[{"title":"Test radio1", "price":"9.000000", "price_type":"fixed", "sku":null, "sort_order":"1"}, {"title":"Test radio2", "price":"10.000000", "price_type":"fixed", "sku":null, "sort_order":"2"}]}, {"title":"Test multiselect title", "type":"multiple", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"8", "values":[{"title":"Test m-select1", "price":"11.000000", "price_type":"fixed", "sku":null, "sort_order":"1"}, {"title":"Test m-select2", "price":"12.000000", "price_type":"fixed", "sku":null, "sort_order":"2"}]}, {"title":"test date title", "type":"date", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"9", "price":"13.000000", "price_type":"fixed"}, {"title":"Test data-time title", "type":"date_time", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"10", "price":"14.000000", "price_type":"fixed"}, {"title":"Test time title", "type":"time", "is_require":"0", "sort_order":"11", "price":"15.000000", "price_type":"fixed"}]'
        )
    );
```

**This is the code**

```
 $options = array();
    foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $_product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->get($data['sku'], true);
        $options = json_decode($data['attributes'], true);
        foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {
            $isRequire = $arrayOption['is_require'] == 0 ? true : false;
            $customOption = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface');
            $customOption->setTitle($arrayOption['title'])
                    ->setType($arrayOption['type'])
                    ->setIsRequire($isRequire)
                    ->setSortOrder($arrayOption['sort_order']);
            if (!in_array($arrayOption['type'], array('drop_down', 'checkbox', 'radio', 'multiple'))) {
                $customOption->setPrice($arrayOption['price'])
                        ->setPriceType($arrayOption['price_type']);
            } else {
                $customOption->setValues($arrayOption['values']);
            }
            $customOption->setProductSku($_product->getSku());
            $customOptions[] = $customOption;
            $_product->setOptions($customOptions)->save();
        }
    }
```

I think it will help you. Thanks to [Igor Melnykov](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/35144/igor-melnykov)