# Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, object-manager, interface

As the part of creating bundle product programmatically in Magento 2.
I am getting below error. Even i removed var/cache and generation.

This may be a duplicate question but none of the answer is working for this issue.

> Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface
>   Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface in
>   \ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 73

Used below code as the reference of [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107638/create-a-bundle-product-programmatically-magento-2)

```
$productExtension = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface::class);
$option = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\OptionInterface::class);
$option->setTitle('Size');
$option->setType('radio');
$option->setRequired(true);
$option->setPosition(1);
//$option->setProductLinks($links);
$productExtension->setBundleOptions([$option]);
$_product->setExtensionAttributes($productExtension);
```

I am using object manager for temporary/quick purpose, will convert the object manager to constructor injunction.

Any one can help me on this issue.

Answer (score 40):

I think you have not mentioned the preference in your di.xml. I also faced the same issue when I was creating custom config xml file module.

I got the issue when I called this code:

```
$testConfig = $this->_objectManager->get('Training\Test\Model\Config\ConfigInterface');
$myNodeInfo = $testConfig->getMyNodeInfo();
```

Below is the sample code I have added in my **di.xml**, may be it may help you to get reference:

`<preference for="Training\Test\Model\Config\ConfigInterface" type="Training\Test\Model\Config" />`

Here I have implemented the interface in `Training\Test\Model\Config` class and my `getMyNodeInfo()` method is defined in that Model.

So based on the the preference defined in **di.xml** the code 
`->get('Training\Test\Model\Config\ConfigInterface');` will create an object of type `Training\Test\Model\Config`.

Comment: its worked for me, Dont user _objectManager

Answer (score 18):

I struggled with this and then found a solution that worked for me in the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html#abstraction-implementation-mappings).

Be sure to add your interface as a preference (correctly) in the `di.xml`, and then run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Comment: My problem was that I placed the di.xml in the etc/frontend folder instead of the etc root by accident, but your answer led me to find that.

Answer (score 10):

You should not use the `ObjectManager`.

Collect your dependencies via `_constructor`.

In case your interface still won't be loaded, check your `di.xml` and validate that a preference is available.

Comment: @ David Lambauer Even i used constructor i am getting Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface in  magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 73

Comment: Did you add the factory to your use statements?

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterfaceFactory;

Answer (score 5):

I tried this mentioned in another thread but it didn't solve:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

Finally, got solved by running `setup:upgrade`:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade

# also run, if in production mode
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I had the same problem locally by going to an old project version, the problem was related to the redis cache, I spent time on it because it's one of the things that we don't necessarily think about; those who use "warden" stack, the command to flush redis locally is: "warden redis flushall".it can help other people

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure module is enabled. You can verify using {{MagentoRoot}}/app/etc/config.php file.
In my case module was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue i.e. cannot instantiate interface for some third party module.
The reason that I found out after debugging that the corresponding module's entry was missing from the app/etc/config.php but the module's code was present in the codebase. 
After manually adding the module's entry in the app/etc/config.php file, the issue got resolved.

Comment: There is no such a file  app/etc/config.xml in M2

Comment: @medina it's config.php, I have updated my answer.

Comment: should be added using `bin/magento set:up` command