# How to add bundle product to cart?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, bundled-product

How to add bundle product to cart automatically with addproduct method , without customization page ,
help me please or.
Is it possible ?

Comment: This has been asked before.
Looks like people point to this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97536